# Centred, underlined headings where the underline is a different colour from the text

Tags: html, css

What's the most straightforward way to style HTML headings such that they are both underlined and horizontally centered? I don't want the underline to extend to the full width of the container, just the words. I also want the underline to be a different colour from the text and some distance away.

At the moment I am using a `span` inside the `h2` to achieve this (in Sass):

```
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        span {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #e6ebdf;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do so without an inner `span` or adding styles to the parent container? Here's the result. Note how the underline is (a) a different colour from the text and, (b) not tight against the bottom of the text the way it would be using `text-decoration: underline`:

[image]

Comment: h2 { text-decoration: underline; text-align: center; }

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the underline should be a different colour from the text. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another idea is to use `table` to center and then apply a gradient where you can easily adjust the size, position and color:

```css
h2 {
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  padding-bottom:5px; /*control the distance*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom /80%   2px   no-repeat;
    /*                     position /width height   */
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Comment: Nice! Works in FF and Edge and also works better when the heading is wrapped. I suggest you add `text-align: center` so that it behaves properly when wrapped.

Comment: @MSC updated, and it will work everywhere ;) gradient is will supported like display:table

Comment: `border-bottom` works just as well as `background: linear-gradient`

Comment: @MSC but you cannot control the width of border-bottom, you can only control height and distance. With gradient you can have a small border and also put it on the right/left/center, etc .. you can also have a multicolored border ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following:-

```css
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Browser support maybe limited though, you may need to check.

Comment: Thanks again but the underline is too close to the text.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that rule, but it doesn't work in Firefox or Edge today.